# Jquery Visualization Chart no showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

Trying to get the jquery visualization working.  The table works fine and and the caption is rendering but there is no data in the chart.  I've followed the example and searched for issues but not seeing what is going wrong.  Nothing is breaking in the console just no data populating the chart.  I've scaled it back thinking before my grid view table was causing the issue and hand coded a table but still the same results no chart.  Here the whole page because its really not that much please let me know what I messed up.

Thanks in advance

```
<head>
<title>test chart</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="Content/visualize-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/visualize-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/visualize.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script src="Scripts/visualize.jQuery.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('table').visualize({ type: 'bar' });
            });//end ready function
</script>
```

```
<body>
<table>
<caption>Test Data</caption>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th scope="col">food</th>
        <th scope="col">auto</th>
        <th scope="col">household</th>
        <th scope="col">furniture</th>
        <th scope="col">kitchen</th>
        <th scope="col">bath</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Mary</th>
        <td>190</td>
        <td>160</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>120</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Tom</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>49</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this particular plugin won't work with jQuery version above 1.7.x

In this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wgu3f/116/) I am plugging your code with version `1.7.2` and it seems to work.